# App bundles and APKs using sensitive permissions - Flutter

Tags: android, xcode, flutter, dart, google-play-console

After submitting my app on the play console, I noticed an error. "Sensitive permissions and APIs."
[image]

But the problem is I am not collecting or asking for any permission from my users. My app is totally transparent, with no ads or in-app purchases.
After checking the error, I found the issue is related to "**android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES**".
[image]

I don't know how to fix this issue, and please guide me. I am pretty new to flutter development.

Comment: your package might be asking
please check all the package you are using

Comment: Sorry for asking this stupid question but how to check if my packages are using permissions or not?

Comment: Provide your pubspec.yaml please with listed dependencies

Comment: Here is it: https://pastebin.com/czxqi6tt (pubspec.yaml)

Comment: No of your packages seems to contain that permission. Check your AndroidManifest.xml for that permission. Check your plugin packages (those include android or iOS code) if they contain that permission in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Dear, here I found something called "QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" I believe is causing the issue in my play console. Can you please look into it and let me know how I can fix this?

https://pastebin.com/rKRpeQ6x (AndroidManifest.xml)

Comment: @Demoxing any solution for QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES ? I removed the permission from the manifest still getting this error

Comment: @Demoxing any update on this? I checked the merged Manifest file and still no trace of QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES. I had it before because of an issue in Flutter some time ago, but removed it now.